# GLMM with non-integer "count" data

Tags: regression, distributions, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, glmm

I'm looking at the difference between bird communities across 5 different vegetation condition levels. Bird species richness data has been recorded across 40 sites, with uneven sample sizes for each of the 5 groups.
From this species richness data, I have calculated a metric which gives a score of the health of the bird community of each site on a scale of 0-1.

I'd like to run a general linear mixed model of bird community by vegetation condition, with site as a random factor but I'm unsure how to treat the family of the data.  Do I treat it as binomial? When I run a `glmer` in `lme4` in R:

```
comm_model <-glmer (cond_metric~State + (1|Site_Number), data_summary, family=binomial())
```

I get the following:

```
    Warning messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
2: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

Any advice on how to deal with this sort of data?

Comment: By a scale of 0 to 1, do you mean that you have several decimal values between 0 and 1? Or you just have binary data (only 0 and only 1)?

Comment: "I have calculated a metric which gives a score of the health of the bird community of each site on a scale of 0-1" can you tell us what this is? It is probably very important

Comment: It's a scale with decimal values between 0 and 1. The metric was calculates as: logit(condition) <- intercept + B1 * species_richness + B2 * proportion_of_small_species and then backtransformed

Comment: For a 0-1 "continuous" variable (in quotes because your data is not truly continuous, but should be pretty close), I'd say a beta regression is most appropriate. However, what is the "health" metric supposed to be reflective of, and what should contribute to it? The reason I am asking is because there are some metrics (in particular, the Hill/diversity numbers of [Hill 1973](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1934352)) which have quite attractive modelling properties, and may be suitable for your problem. Species richness itself is one of the Hill numbers.